# Does the spell-checker break because I'm using English (Canada)?

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

I switched from Firefox to Chrome and my only disappointment is that the flagging of spelling errors seems to be erratic. Is this possibly because I'm using the English (Canada) language setting rather than English (United States)?

In other words, if the English (Canada) dictionary is small (which seems likely) is this why Chrome is missing obvious spelling mistakes?

Comment: Where are you from?

Comment: Canada. I like my use of 'u' :)